# Is there a way to limit a JSONArray size in Java?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

For example, if I have a JSONObject that contains an array of 150 items, is there any way to make a JSONArray of only the first 5 items in the JSONObject?

I have this:

```
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("cast"));
```

But I want to avoid calling JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonObject.getString("cast")); because then I make an array of the entire JSONObject instead of just the first five items.

Thanks!

Comment: only add a subset?

Comment: @ScaryWombat I haven't tried that, what is an example of that?

Comment: see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOfRange(int[],%20int,%20int)

Comment: @ScaryWombat I would still need to get an initial JSONArray though right? I'm trying to only parse the JSONObject once due to performance issues with parsing a large JSONObject into a JSONArray :(

Comment: No I am saying do not return all the array as json, but only return some of the array as json - if you have access to that code

Comment: @ScaryWombat sorry, I think I didn't make my question clear. I don't have an actual array yet, I'm trying to make a JSONArray based off of the JSONObject but only with the first 5 items in the JSONObject.

Comment: You might want to use `JSONTokenizer` but it's hard to use. As an alternative, Gson and Jackson provide well-written and easy to use streaming APIs -- maybe it's worth to consider them?

Answer (score 0):

You can either modify the JSON response or create a new JSONArray and put the first five items. Please refer the code:

```
    JSONArray studentArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("students");

    JSONArray firstFiveStudentArray = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
        JSONObject studentObj = studentArray.optJSONObject(i);
        if (studentObj != null) {
            firstFiveStudentArray.put(studentObj);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how would I modify the JSON response? I'm trying to avoid calling the `JSONArray studentArray = jsonObject.optJSONArray("students");` due to performance issues as the JSONObject is quite large and I only want the first 5 items

Comment: yes, I have a JSONObject with the network response but I want to make a JSONArray from it with only the first 5 items

Comment: i think use limit 5 in server you will get  exactly 5 json object.otherwise use same @ muazzhud given answer

Comment: @android_jain How do i limit 5 in server? I am using a public API to get the JSON